# echoing a jquery animation function with php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, echo

I am trying to echo this jquery function, with php. basically if the script detects a field of a form is not filled in then it will echo this and make the input text box turn red.

It works fine when it is not being echo'd.

```
echo('
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(\'input\').animate({backgroundColor:\"#F00\"},200);
    });
</script>
');
```

any ideas?

Comment: Don't ask why it doesn't work. Look at what it outputs and ask why that is different to the code that does work. If you run the PHP and look at the generated output, the reason it doesn't work becomes pretty obvious.

Comment: Chances are the echo is not getting run. Make sure this is in a PHP file in the appropriate tags (<?php), etc. As with @David Dorward, you're going to have to debug it on your own.

Comment: @Stefan — the output from running that echo has big, bold JS syntax errors.

Comment: @Black Magic: Please do not use parens for language constructs like `echo`. It is considered bad practice.

Comment: @David Dorward-It is working fine now, mind telling me the JS syntax errors?

Comment: @Black Magic — you ask that after Olafski has spoon fed you the answer and 2 minutes after you've responded to his answer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have to escape your quotes when the string is within single quotes. PHP won't parse the string, it will be output literally.

Comment: OH that's it. This is the first time I've used escapes.

Answer (score 1):

You're over-doing it on the string escape. To keep it simple, just use single quotes around the echoed string, and use double quotes inside it. Something like:

```
echo('
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("input").animate({backgroundColor: "#F00"}, 200);
    });
</script>
');
```

When you're `echo`ing stuff, there are indeed some cases when you need to escape the quotes, but most of the times you can simply get away with it by using different types of quotes. For example, I'll never get it why people still do something like:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\">";
```

as opposed to

```
echo '<input type="text" name="username">';
```

which makes your life a whole lot easier when you have to modify it.

Hope this helps !

Comment: So single and double quotes are interchangable?

Comment: Not necessarily. Take for exampe proEvil's example. If you were to add a `\n` at the end of your string, by encasing it in single quotes it would be output literally, as opposed to using double quotes which would output it as intended (i.e. new line character).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `\"` there, just `"`

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore: a hex-color-value is no numeric value you can use for animate() .
By this, the error is fixed by removing the backslashes from the doublequotes, but your animation wouldn't show any effect.

Answer (score -1):

i didnt test it, but try that:

```
$nl = "\n";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.$nl;
echo '    $(document).ready(function() {'.$nl;
echo '        $("input").animate({backgroundColor:"#F00"},200);'.$nl;
echo '    });'.$nl;
echo '</script>'.$nl;
```

the $nl="\n" is only for linebreak (I prefer to use singlequotes in echos, so php didn't have to parse the content - just echo out).